# How to claim Bitcoin Cash from Block.io

Tags: bitcoin-cash, block.io

Initially Block.io stated they would support Bitcoin Cash in September and that never happened.  :(  After reaching out to them they stated:

*"The Bitcoin Cash network seems to be dying in favor of the new Segwit2x fork its proponents want to push. While we continue to index the Bitcoin Cash blockchain, we do not believe full support for this network is merited given its low adoption.
If you wish to use your addresses to claim your Bitcoin Cash equivalent in the mean, see block.io/dashboard/settings -> Access Private Keys, and then claim your Bitcoin Cash from a service that supports that network."*

At this point I attempted to transfer Bitcoin Cash to Btc.com with their tool but it is stating that no funds were located so they probably are not compatible with Block.io.

Does anyone have a service that will support the transfer of Bitcoin Cash from Block.io with my private keys so I can get it off their exchange and into my wallet?  Any thoughts or assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried importing private keys to https://electroncash.org ?

Comment: Thank you.  I have not and honestly no idea what electroncash is about.  Utilize Coinbase, KeepKey and a few other exchanges but outside of that, they have been absolutely useless in their support.  I will look into electroncash and see what that is about.

Comment: It's Bitcoin Cash version of Electrum, a lightweight wallet. It allows you to import private keys.

Comment: Sorry for delay in responding.  Was out of country on business trip. Thank you so much for taking the time to respond.  Already removed all actual bitcoins from wallet prior to trying with btc.com so will try again with electrum.    Will let you know and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible! But it's complicated :]
The main reason is block.io are using multisig addresses, meaning that it's not the usual address that you can redeem funds with only one private key, but here we require two private keys to sign every transaction.

**EDIT - This solution used to work for some time, but it doesn't work at the moment**

It seems that blockdozer.com changed their API and their AJAX/CORS policy in some way that makes it impossible to query outputs and to submit transactions. I was able to overcome their AJAX by disabling security on the browser, however the raw transaction that's being generated contains special characters such as "|" and the API doesn't support that. It did work about a month ago though, but not any more

Since Ik'm no expert on this I submitted a comment to the developer that implemented bitcoin cash support in Coinb.in, I'll update here once I get a response. Here's the PR and comment in Github:

https://github.com/OutCast3k/coinbin/pull/113

**Phase one - Acquire your private keys**

First phase is to your private keys from Block.io - Log into your wallet, go to "Settings", then press "Private Key Access". You'll get an email with instructions how to proceed. At the end of this process you should have a file that contains something like this :

```
* Address: 3ET4FuXvHahN4WwrJ3dyCLsoVbDVZtVEUU
* Address Type: P2SH
* Required Signatures: 2
* Redeem Script: ....
* Redeem HEX: 5221039960aa771270362b7e49400433e103c59e12c6a43a946d4b048f7efcc68bc0bf21028825d729387c6b0aafae1c47802c62d7f965de1800d6122143c681044c50700452ae     
* Public Keys: ["039960aa771270362b7e49400433e103c59e12c6a43a946d4b048f7efcc68bc0bf","028825d729387c6b0aafae1c47802c62d7f965de1800d6122143c681044c507004"]
* Private Keys: ["KyubGochD3MkXW4KkT95K6FXbZSrtHg6creF6xaRDc9C3qkyidza","KxFLJ2n76i2W9WB2YdJd1zCL2Kmgpk1vfB2XEynSpQWsYCe4bfqn"]
```

**Phase two - coinb.in**

I tried to do it the easy way using Electron Cash - there's an option there to import multi sig addresses but it doesn't work. I had to sign the transaction manually and broadcast it to the BCH main network. coinb.in is an awesome tool to do that, however at the moment the pull request for using BCH isn't merged yet, I deployed a version of the tool here :

http://galed.codus.net/coinbin/

Alternatively, If you want to be extra cautious you can run the tool on your local machine by running these commands :

```
git clone https://github.com/dabura667/coinbin.git
cd coinbin
git checkout bitcoincash
open index.html
```

**Phase three - signing a transaction and braodcasting**

PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE WATCH THE INSTRUCTIONS in this youtube video to get a better sense of what needs to happen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUSVmLegj8k - If you're dealing with large sums of BCH you could end up losing everything, so please be careful!

The one difference is that you need to be careful to choose the bitcoin cash network, otherwise you'll be broadcasting transactions on the BTC network:

- Click New -> Transaction
- Enter the redeem HEX that you received from block.io in the first box (Address, WIF key or Redeem Script)
- Click on "Advanced options" and change the network to "Bitcoin Cash mainnet"
- Put in the amount you want to transfer and the address, make sure that the fee is not too high
- Click submit, you will get a long HEX string. copy it
- Go to "Sign" , paste the string, paste the first private key from the file that block.io sent you, click "Submit", Copy the string
- Paste the string into the second box, copy paste the second private key from the block.io file, click Submit, copy the output
- Go to "Broadcast", paste the string and submit.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to this.  Wow!  Truly appreciate. Going to try and process everything you wrote since as knowledgeable I am with all this to the average "joe public" I have no clue on half of what you said. lol   Seriously will take a look in between football games on Sunday and figure what you said.

Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hello, I tried following your steps, but when I add the redeem HEX, I get the following error:  Unexpected error, unable to retrieve unspent outputs!

Comment: @Human I see what the issue is, Unfortunately blockdozer.com that originally supported this method changed their API and there CORS policy so 1. You're unable to retrieve outputs since they block the source for Ajax requests (Which is solvable), and 2. Once you sign the transaction they changed the format that they accept. I'll edit the solution to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import your private keys into a wallet which supports Bitcoin Cash. Firstly a warning, your private key is all that is needed to spend all bitcoin and bitcoin cash sent to the corresponding address, so do not give it out to anyone.

You could try using [Electron Cash](https://www.electroncash.org/) as suggested in the comments on your question. Note there was an official warning about using electron cash [here](https://electrum.org/bcc2.txt), but I haven't heard reports of it acting maliciously as of yet, a lot of people have used it.

It is highly suggested that you send your actual bitcoins to a new address before importing the old address into electron cash to claim the BCC on it, simply as a precaution